# How to run a command in VBS in high memory

Tags: pdf, doc

Saving or exporting a word document as pdf takes very long, using VBscript. Is there way to run save as on high priority or to allocate high memory to the command so that it execute faster.

...

Set doc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(myfiledoc)

Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat myfilepdf,17,False,0,0,,,0,False,True,1
...

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "high memory"? What makes you think that the problem is memory-bound?

Comment: Agreed - check your Task Manager and see if you're running out of memory or CPU.

Comment: Idea is to reduce the execution time for the export command..